# Picasso not loading a particular working image url

Tags: android, image, picasso

Picasso just suddenly stops loading a particular URL that has always been working before. I tried any other URL and it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
Picasso.get()
        .load( "https://api.kliqr.com/images/icons/banks/uba.png")
        .transform(circularTransform)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cash_note)
        .into(holder.bankIconImageView);
```

The URL works fine when it is tested on the browser. This is a very weird problem because it worked fine before.

Comment: What version of Picasso are you using? Did you tried Glide with the given url? It is very similar to Picasso.

Comment: I’m using the latest version of Picasso. 
Also i have tried with Glide, the same thing happens, doesn’t load that specific url

Comment: Is there any error message on the debug log in android studio? Did you tried other png images of other websites with a similar resolution?

Comment: No error message, but I logged Picasso and i get this 504 error which i believe couldn't load the image. I tried other images works fine too

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you have also posted error screenshot or log but I will suggest to check if you have added internet permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

As you are saying it was working fine before, you might have added.
But re-check for that
Hope it helps